# CorePlot: CPTPieChart change position inside CPTGraphHostingView?

Tags: graph, frame, core-plot, pie-chart

Is posible change an frame of CPTPieChart inside of CPTGraphHostingView????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly, but you can control the pie chart size and position in the plot area (which is the same size as the hosting view if all of the paddings are 0). Use the `centerAnchor` property to position the center of the pie. The x and y coordinates of the anchor point are given as a fraction of the size of the plot area. The default of (0.5, 0.5) is the middle of the plot area. The `pieRadius` is the radius of the pie in pixels.

Comment: Yes, in my case the default value of centerAnchor or anchorPoint is (0,0) and i can´t change this values... i try this: [piePlot setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)]; and this [piePlot setCenterAnchor:CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)];

Comment: The `centerAnchor` defaults to (0.5, 0.5). It is a read/write property so you should be able to change it to anything you want. The x and y components should be between 0 and 1.

Comment: I dont know why i cant change it, have i used the correctly method: setCenterAnchor??? This change must be after create a piePlot or in other method? Thanks Eric!!

Comment: Yes, that should work. You can also use property syntax: `piePlot.centerAnchor = CGPointMake(0.25, 0.75);`. This assumes, of course, that `piePlot` is a valid `CPTPieChart` instance.

Comment: oK, I go to post my pie chart definition, and probe your syntax.

Comment: oK,i´ve probed your solution and it´s correct, i don´t know why in other time don´t found this, but now perfect!!!. Thanks Eric!!